# Rename types with graphql-codegen

Tags: typescript, graphql, graphql-codegen

I'm working on a legacy codebase where, in our GraphQL schema, an interface was defined as 'Subscription':

```
  interface Subscription {
    fieldOne: String
    fieldTwo: String
  }

  type FirstSubscriptionType implements Subscription {
    anotherField: String
  }

  type SecondSubscriptionType implements Subscription {
    yetAnotherField: String
  }
```

This has worked fine (we don't use subscriptions and don't have plans to), but when I try to use `graphql-codegen` to auto-generate Typescript types for us to use in our frontend code, the `generates` step fails with this error:

```
Subscription root type must be Object type if provided, it cannot be Subscription
```

The obvious answer is to rename the interface. Sure enough, renaming to something like `ISubscription` fixes everything. I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid having to change anything in our schema and have `graphql-codegen` translate/rename the type in just the frontend code. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party but I have found an answer.

I leveraged the [lifecycle](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/docs/config-reference/lifecycle-hooks#beforeallfilewrite) hooks that GraphQL Codegen exposes to call a typescript transformer script which de-dupes the type definitions.

Configure your codegen as shown below, so it calls the script after generating the file(s). If you need to de-dupe multiple files, you can change the lifecycle hook from `afterOneFileWrite` to `afterAllFileWrite`. The script will receive the filepath for the generated file(s) as process args.

```
import type { CodegenConfig } from "@graphql-codegen/cli";

const config: CodegenConfig = {
    overwrite: true,
    schema: [
        {
            "/source/": {},
        },
    ],
    hooks: {
        afterOneFileWrite: ["ts-node scripts/resolve-type-conflicts"],
        afterAllFileWrite: ["prettier --write"],
    },
    documents: [
        /** etc */
    ],
    generates: {
 
        "src/": {
            /* Whatever your config is */
        },
    },
};

export default config;
```

Then write the `resolve-type-conflicts.ts` script as such

```
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as ts from "typescript";
const resolveTypeConflicts = () => {
    // this will be the generated file from codegen
    const [, , file] = process.argv;

    // we track how often we have seen a given variable name here
    const collisionsCounter: Record<string, number> = {};

    const transformerFactory: ts.TransformerFactory<ts.Node> =
        (context) => (rootNode) => {
            function visitTypeAliasDeclaration(node: ts.Node): ts.Node {
                // recurse through the Typescript AST of the file
                node = ts.visitEachChild(
                    node,
                    visitTypeAliasDeclaration,
                    context
                );

                /**
                *
                * short-circuit logic to prevent handling nodes we don't
                * care about. This might need to be adjusted based on what 
                * you need to de-dupe. In my case only types were being duped
                */
                if (!ts.isTypeAliasDeclaration(node)) {
                    return node;
                }

                /**
                * you may not need to cast to lowercase. In my case I had
                * name collisions that different cases which screwed up a
                * later step
                */
                const nameInLowerCase = node.name.text.toLowerCase();
                const suffix = collisionsCounter[nameInLowerCase] ?? "";
                const encounterCount = collisionsCounter[nameInLowerCase];
                collisionsCounter[nameInLowerCase] =
                    typeof encounterCount === "undefined"
                        ? 1
                        : encounterCount + 1;
                return context.factory.createTypeAliasDeclaration(
                    node.modifiers,
                    `${node.name.text}${suffix}`,
                    node.typeParameters,
                    node.type
                );
            }
            return ts.visitNode(rootNode, visitTypeAliasDeclaration);
        };

    const program = ts.createProgram([file], {});

    const sourceFile = program.getSourceFile(file);
    const transformationResult = ts.transform(sourceFile, [transformerFactory]);
    const transformedSourceFile = transformationResult.transformed[0];
    const printer = ts.createPrinter();

    // the deduped code is here as a string
    const result = printer.printNode(
        ts.EmitHint.Unspecified,
        transformedSourceFile,
        undefined
    );
    fs.writeFileSync(file, result, {});
};
resolveTypeConflicts();
```